# Update A star column till root node on adding new entry

Tags: mysql, sql, recursion

I don't know how to solve this case need some guidance I have a scenario where I have to `update` a `star` column field of root node on adding every child entry so far I have done this, its updating the `star` column of directly linked nodes not the full path like if `A` is `root` and  `B C & D` are `children` then `A` `star` column gets update now if `C` `B` or `D` adds something below them `A` stars column doesn't gets updated, I have less knowledge about triggers and sql and I am stuck I have searched a lot but didn't find a solution here is the method of sql which is doing all this so far.

```
DELIMITER @@
DROP PROCEDURE p_prefix_nodes_add_new_paths_after_insert @@
CREATE PROCEDURE cvs.p_prefix_nodes_add_new_paths_after_insert
(
    param_node_new_id INT UNSIGNED,
    param_node_parent_id INT UNSIGNED
)
BEGIN

INSERT INTO `prefix_nodes_paths` (
    `ancestor_id`,
    `descendant_id`,
    `path_length`
)
SELECT
    `ancestor_id`,
    `param_node_new_id`,
    `path_length` + 1
FROM
    `prefix_nodes_paths`
WHERE `descendant_id` = `param_node_parent_id`
UNION
ALL
SELECT
    `param_node_new_id`,
    `param_node_new_id`,
    0 ;
    Update prefix_nodes_paths
    Set stars=stars+1
    where ancestor_id=param_node_parent_id;
END @@ 
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Id's suggest you to use the [nested set model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model) technique to store your tree-like data in the SQL database. Your queries would become a lot more handy, faster and simpler when you try to get descendants or ancestors of the specific node.

Comment: Yes i tried nested set model and i didn't knew how to assign left right values to the nodes, because i have to handle a generic case where i don't know the number of users, i have implemented closure table method, and i think its easy to implement other then nested set model, adjacency list and path enumeration model

Comment: What programming language do you use? Have you considered using some of already written libraries for nested set model? Normally it's a way simpler to use a library than implement this thing by yourself. And it doesn't matter how many users you will have - there are a lot of cases when left/right values have to be regenerated during updates, using very simple calculations.

Comment: i am doing this in php, and i cam across some libraries but i didnt knew how to use them, if you have any useful information kindly let me know about it, and i am also new in web development field so i dont know really much stuff...